# Unable to change the Server URL in android in IBM mobile first platform

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am migrating worklight hybrid projects from 6.0.2 to 6.3. When i do this and install the application on to android device, I am unable to edit worklight settings and change the URL.However the same feature is working on IOS devices.
But when I create new project on 6.3 , the above feature works fine in android as well.
In application-descriptor.xml worklight settings is enabled though.
 .
 However when I try to change the URL in android device by editing the settings, below exception is thrown.

02-16 18:48:27.173: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(552): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
02-16 18:48:27.173: E/ViewRootImpl(27590): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-16 18:48:50.155: E/Watchdog(552): !@Sync 706

Settings pop up is not showing up , to change the URL. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worklight Settings is unreliable on Android devices using API Level 10 and above. The settings screen may appear but not work, or the Options Menu that invokes it may not appear at all, etc.

However, starting MobileFirst Platform 6.3 there is dedicated API for setting & getting the Server URL, enabling you to change it during runtime: `WL.App.getServerUrl` and `WL.App.setServerUrl`.

There is a blog post on this new ability that explains how to use the API methods as well as provides a sample application. You can follow it and integrate it in your application instead of using the Worklight Settings screen in Android.

Blog post: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/02/02/changing-server-url-runtime/

Comment: I am migrating worklight hybrid projects from 6.0.2 to 6.3. When i do this and install the application on to android device, I am unable to edit worklight settings and change the URL.However the same feature is working on IOS devices.
But when I create new project on 6.3 , the above feature works fine in android as well.
In application-descriptor.xml worklight settings is enabled though.
 <worklightSettings include="true"/>

Comment: Thank u but This way is not accepted. Worklight settings is the approved way. Any other suggestions pls.

Comment: Worklight Settings will not work if your Android device's is of a newer module and OS version, because The Action Bar - which replaces the Options Menu in Android - is not supported. You cannot use Worklight Settings any more in newer devices. This is both mentioned in the documentation as well as in a warning message in LogCat. Your only alternative in 6.3 is the new APIs allowing you to create UI to control the Server URL, which is a far more powerful way to work. This is your only available and accepted option. Use it.